# Sending id from ajax to controller for deleting data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I am getting some users data from database through Ajax. I added some checkboxes to the table for deleting data. I write code for that but I don't know how to send user id from the ajax to the controller.It would be nice if someone will help me. Below is my code

//Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
            });

            $('select[name="class_id"]').on('change', function() {
                var classID = $(this).val();
                if(classID) {

                    $.ajax({

                        url: '/attendance/ajax/'+classID,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data) {

                            var markup = '';
                        markup += '<tr><th style="width: 2%" class="align-middle text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="options"></th><th style="width: 2%" class="align-middle text-center">#</th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student ID<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student Name<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Attendance<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Date<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%;" class="align-middle text-center">Actions</th> <tr>';

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                            markup += '<tr> <td><input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]"></td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.id+'" name="id[]">' + value.id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.student_id+'" name="student_id[]">' + value.student_id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.first_name+'" name="first_name[]"><input type="hidden" value="'+value.last_name+'" name="last_name[]">' + value.first_name+ ' '  + value.last_name +  '<td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.attendance+'" name="attendance[]">' + value.attendance + '</td>' +  '<td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.created_at+'" name="created_at[]">' + value.created_at + '</td>' + '<td style=" width=12%" class="text-center"> <a><button title="Edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span></button></a> </td>' +  '</td> <tr>';

                        });
                            $('table[id="studentsData"]').html(markup);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

//Submit button for deleting

```
<form method="post" action="delete/attendance" class="form-inline">

            {{csrf_field()}}

            {{method_field('delete')}}



            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="checkBoxArray" id="" class="form-control">

                    <option value="">Delete</option>

                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" name="delete_all" class="btn btn-primary">

            </div>
        </form>
```

//Route

```
Route::delete('/students/delete/attendance', 'AttendanceController@deleteAttendance');
```

//Controller

```
 public function deleteAttendance(Request $request, $id) {
        if ($request->delete_single) {
            $this->destroy($id);
        }
        if(isset($request->delete_all) && !empty($request->checkBoxArray)) {

            $attendances = StudentsAttendance::findOrFail($request->checkBoxArray);

            foreach($attendances as $attendance) {

                $attendance->delete();

            }

            return redirect()->back();

        } else {

            return redirect()->back();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have two delete buttons (one that removes the checked attendances & one for deleting all of them)?

Comment: No I have only checkboxes where user can select one or multiple

Comment: So the "delete_all" button must send the id's of the selected checkboxes to the controller, then remove them ?

Comment: delete_all button not sending anything to the controller. It just redirect me to the same controller. Actually I dont have any input on the tbody which can send id of the student. And i dont know how to setup that in my markup which we made

Comment: My last comment was an question to be sure what you want before answering you, so what's the answer of _Must the "delete_all" button send the id's of the selected checkboxes to the controller, then remove them?_ Is that wat you want?

Comment: Yes Thats what I want

Comment: You're adding the checkbox just in the head of the table, isn't it should be added to every row in the table ?

Comment: No I added to my tbody too. Check that in the markup. My tbody is in the javascript. And Its also working perfectly. I have checkbox in every row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191440/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-hasnain-kahn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to send the set of ids to your action, create a POST route first :

```
Route::post('/students/delete/attendance', 'AttendanceController@deleteAttendance');
```

Then you must to attach the `id` with every checkbox like :

```
<input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]" value="'+value.id+'">
```

And update you form action to :

```
<form method="post" action="/students/delete/attendance" class="form-inline">
```

Give it a go and check if you're getting all the selected id's in your `deleteAttendance` action by adding `dd()` at the top :

```
public function deleteAttendance(Request $request, $id) {
    dd( $request->checkBoxArray );

    ...
}
```

Comment: Now its going me null value at the backend

Comment: What about `dd( $request->all() );`

Comment: Giving me this array **array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "pGRXX9H599o2yT12n8XXCZLwG5mtVrJeHiDnWNmx"
  "_method" => "delete"
  "checkBoxArray" => null
  "delete_all" => "Submit Query"
]**

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax url is diffrent from your route.

```
ajax : /attendance/ajax/{id}
route : /students/delete/attendance
```

if we follow same instruction from controller, it's need id, so change the ajax url to : `'/students/delete/attendance/' +classID`

Your ajax type is wrong, change `GET` to `DELETE` (same as route).

then your route is not use ID, but your pass url to route and controller with id.

```
Route::delete('/students/delete/attendance/{id}', 'AttendanceController@deleteAttendance');
```

on your controller just do :

```
public function deleteAttendance(Request $request, $id) {
    $query = StudentsAttendance::findOrFail($id);
    $query->delete();
}
```

if you want delete multiple student, it will be diffrent code.

Comment: Yes I want multiple deletes

Comment: Pls explain me how i can delete multiple data ?

Comment: you can pass id and run delete query inside foreach

Comment: But I cannot change the GET type to DELETE. Because when i changed that then i am not getting any data

Comment: you can use POST if want return data .. [HERE](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/how-to-do-an-ajax-delete)